# HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization but I have the correct information in my application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBpxR.png)Hiii! I tried to create an application using spring boot.I tried to use a postgres database in heroku but I got the following error message with hikari-pool initialization.
And I am sure that I wrote the correct information ABOUT the heroku's database in my application.properties`

Comment: Can you please post relevant parts of your configuration and the output you get? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the error stack trace and simplified version of your code snippet?

Comment: server.port=5432

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=40000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.0.0.83:5432/test1

spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=12345678
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME= org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Answer (score 0):

my pom.xml :    

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.2.RELEASE
 

telmaApi
telma
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
telma
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```